# resolving promises in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a function in my controller, which calls the service and returns a promise 
When the promise is resolved, i need to assign scope variable with the returned success data from service.
but the scope variable is not getting assigned, since this is async call and promise not being resolve before jumping to next line of code 
Is there a way that i could resolve the promise first before, i can execute the next line of code to avoid errors

Controller code -

```
function getUserInfo(){

      memberSerice.getDetails(userId).then(function(userdetails){

          $scope.userInfo = userdetails;
    });
}
```

memberService code -

```
function getDetails(){

    return promise;

}
```

Here, the Scope variable is not being assigned when the html is rendered. It is getting assigned with promise value at later point which is breaking the UI.

So how can i wait this promise to be resolved, and scope variable is assigned before i start executing the next line of code ?

Thanks,
Nikitha

Comment: Why is the html rendered immediately? What do you expect it to show in the period between starting the action and resolving the promise? No, you cannot block.

Comment: it is a checkbox on page, which makes service call to which i need to pass userdetails, returned by promise as parameter. But this parameter is not yet populated when a submit a request to different service. So, i want to wait for promise to be resolved , and then pass the assigned scope value as parameter to different service. What would be the solution for this

Comment: Put the code that passes the value to the next thing in your `then` callback.

Comment: I tried that as well. But, the issue is there are almost 7 service calls which are dependent on this user details return value.  Does all of this service calls go inside then?

Comment: Yes, is there a problem with that? Of course each of them can go in its own `.then()` (on the same promise) if you want/need to separate them logically.

Answer (score 0):

Can you resolve the value in your route to the controller?

Something like this:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/:userId", {
        templateUrl: "myView.html",
        controller: "myController",
        resolve: {
            userDetails: function(myService){
                return myService.getDetails();
        }
    }
})
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller("myController", function (userDetails) {
    $scope.userinfo = userDetails;
});
```

Comment: no , i cannot do that actually. Is there a efficient way i could wait till the promise is resolved, before jumping to next line of code?